# How to add more parameters in ajax call when we pass the upload Excel to action method in controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my code an Excel file is uploaded by user in view HTML and get the file by ajax and pass to an action method in ASP.NET MVC. My code is working fine but my problem is I want to add two more parameters pass to action method with the file. How do I achieve this?

```
function uploadUserProfileDetails() {
    var excelUpload = $('#excelUpload').get(0);
    var excelfiles = excelUpload.files;
    var excelFileData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < excelfiles.length; i++) {
        excelFileData.append(excelfiles[i].name, excelfiles[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: "multipart/form-data",
            url: "/VCModule/UploadVCSchedule",
            data: excelFileData,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  var abc = {
    'modelfieldname':excelFileData,
    'modelfieldname1':data1,
    'modelfieldname2':data2,
};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        url: "/VCModule/UploadVCSchedule",
        data: abc,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How I get the values in ActionMethod in Controller

Comment: give name as of controller and their method i.e. controller/method

Answer (score 0):

Hers is the Solution working.

```
var awardfamilyid = 105;

//in Ajax method :-
excelFileData.append(awardfamilyid, JSON.stringify(awardfamilyid));

//In Action Method :-

int AwardFamilyID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.Keys[0]);
```